# Make the button open a specific tab in chrome

Tags: javascript, html

Is there any way to change the script in page so i can make a button go to a specific page? Like, using inspect element? I want the open a page and add a script in the button of this page, so it can go to the url i add.

Comment: So you would go to an url? Why don't just go directly to that url?

Answer (score 0):

only if you have created that target tab. then you can send a message with anything and use eval in document in target tab